# Delete files created before '7' days regardless of the modified time

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have to delete the log files older than 7 days even if they were modified within a period of 7 days. But the only solution I can find anywhere is based on find command using mtime option as below:

`find /path/to/files -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;`

What is the possible solution to this problem.

Comment: What exactly is problem/question?

Comment: @AvalSarri Is there any option other than 'find -mtime' to delete files older than x days.

Comment: the creation date is generally not stored, which is why there is not an option in find, if you using logrotate etc, then there should be no reason a log gets edited to change the modified time, if your rolling your own logging, then make a file or use a database which references when the log was created then use that

Comment: @LawrenceCherone using logrotate is not an option available for me at present.

Comment: Can you put the creation date into the filename?

Comment: @Thomas yes I can do that, infact I have already done that. Please see below command.

** find "$FILE_PATH" -type f -size +2k -exec gzip -k --suffix $(date +"-%d%h%y-%H:%M:%S.gz") {} \; **

Comment: @AyushKapil : Does [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/397442/) help in understanding the problem?

Comment: Not all Linux filesystems _track_ creation time at all. In fact, most of them don't. Usually, modification time, metadata-change time, and access time are the only timestamps that exist, so the data to compare creation time _simply doesn't exist_.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a [filesystem that tracks file birth time and a current enough Linux kernel, glibc and GNU coreutils](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91200/367593), you can do something like

```sh
weekago=$(date -d "last week" +%s)
for file in /path/to/files/*; do
    birthdate=$(stat -c %W "$file")
    if [[ $birthdate -gt 0 && $birthdate -lt $weekago ]]; then
      printf "%s\n" "$file"
      # Uncomment when you're sure you're getting just the files you want
      # rm -- "$file"
    fi
done
```